# left join 2 tables and group_concat related articles to each category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, concatenation

i built 2 tables (articles,categories)
how can i output all categories with their related articles below each one 
ex:

category-->mobile

articles-->1-samsung galaxy s3,2-samsung galaxy s4 review,3-samsung note 3

then

category-->laptop

articls-->1-hp pavilion g6,2-lenovo 2014,3-dell inspiron15r

......etc for all othe categories

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `art_id` int(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `relcat_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `art_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `art_subtitle` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `art_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `art_snippet` text NOT NULL,
  `art_tags` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `art_download` text NOT NULL,
  `art_instructor` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `art_dt` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`art_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `cat_id` int(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `cat_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `cat_ref` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `cat_img` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

i tried the following query using group_concat but didn't work

```
select relcat_id,GROUP_CONCAT(art_id),art_title,art_subtitle,art_desc,art_tags,art_download,cat_name,cat_img from articles left join categories on articles.relcat_id=categories.cat_id where relcat_id=1 group by relcat_id
```

Comment: Could you please post some dummy data that we can test assumptions with?

Comment: Do you want the list of the article ids for each category only, or do you want all the meta-data associated with them too? Why do you have `where relcat_id=1` in your query?